# Optimizing derivatives of smooth step functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, optimization, partial-derivative

Consider the collection $A$ of all infinitely many times differentiable functions $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ that are $0$ on $(-\infty,0)$, increasing in $[0,1]$ and $1$ in $[1,+\infty)$. It is easy enough to show that $A\neq \emptyset$. I am interested in the derivatives of the functions in $A$. By the mean value Theorem,  if  $B=\{\sup f':f\in A\}$ then $\inf B\ge 1$. By convolving with mollifiers, it follows that $\inf B=1$.

Question 1: Is this infimum actually a minimum, i.e. is there an $f\in A$ with $\sup f'=1$?

Question 2: Can this be generalized to higher dimensions? Namely, if $A$ consists of infinitely differentiable maps $\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ that are $1$ on the cube $[-1,1]^n$ and $0$ outside $[-2,2]^n$, does $B=\{\|\nabla f\|_{\infty}:f\in A\}$ have minimum $1$? Can we similarly deal with the other $p$-norms of the gradient, or use balls instead of cubes etc?

Question 3: Can we simultenously also minimize the higher order derivatives of $f$ [say, finitely many of them at the same time]?

Does anyone have a reference where these questions are answered?

Edit: The answer to Q1 is negative. The answer to Q2 is positive for the infimum, and the answer to Q3 is also negative. I am still interested in references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, the answer is no: $f\in A \implies \sup_{[0,1]}f'>1.$ Proof: Suppose to the contrary that $f'(x) \le 1, x\in [0,1].$ Because $f'(0) = 0,$ there is $0<a<1$ such that $f'(x)\le 1/2$ for $x\in [0,a].$ Thus

$$1 = f(1)-f(0) = \int_0^1 f'(x)\,dx = \int_0^a f' + \int_a^1 f' \le (1/2)\cdot a + 1\cdot (1-a) < 1,$$

contradiction.